# What is different between setState and this.setState in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

my friend, I want to know what is different between this two method setState and this.setState in Flutter:

```
  exampleMethod() async {
    this.setState(() {});
    setState(() {});
  }
```

Comment: There is no difference

Comment: OK, thank you @mousetail (-;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State-class.html) setState is a method for state class, since Stateful widget's state class extends State, you can call a classes method using `this` or directly. And in general, `this.var` is the same as calling `var` unless you have another variable with the same name inside your scope.